# If and when "return false;" is useful in a function called onclick/ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As stated in the title. Is it useful?

I don't intend to use it to change the behavior, but I saw that many times functions are completed with a `return false;` statement.

Shall I use `return false;` in any case where the return value is **not** used?

Comment: It isn't about best practice. This *changes* the behavior...

Comment: It depends on whether you want it to return false.

Comment: usually `"return false;"` in click handler in markup used for preventing submit, in other cases it not useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return false, it prevents the browsers default behavior, so as others said, its not a question of "best practice", it's a question of "what do you want your code to do?"

For example if you return false from an onclick event on a link, it will cause the browser not to follow the link.

I assume you are seeing return false a lot because people tend to want to override the browsers default behavior.

In your situation, you should decide to either return false or true depending on what you want your code to do. Either prevent browser behavior or not.

Comment: crystal clear, thank you :-) (I also edited the question to make it clearer)